# How can i extract n elements out of p in a std::vector with X elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, cluster-analysis, stdvector

I have a vector with X elements, how can I extract n elements (3 in the example below) out of p (6 in the example) from the vector?
Here is how I did it.

```cpp
//vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> a {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
                       23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35};

int X = a.size();

// code to extract 3 elements of 6 until the end of the vector
for (int i=0; i< a.size(); i+=6)
{

        if (i >= a.size())
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sub_indices.push_back(i);
        }

        if ( (i+1) >= a.size())
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sub_indices.push_back(i+1);
        }

        if ((i+2) >= a.size())
        {
            break;
        }
        else {
            sub_indices.push_back(i+2);
        }
}
```

Display result would output:

```
10 11 12 (drop three elements) 16 17 18 (drop three elements) 22 23 24  (drop three elements) 28 29 30 (drop three elements) 34 35
```

I did it like this but can anyone show me a more efficient way?

Comment: You know that you can have loops inside of loops? And that a loop "increment" expression doesn't have to be e.g. `i++`, you can do something like `i += p`. And that for vector iterators you can also use `+=` to step more than one element.

Comment: Check out initializer lists, they would make the code with the `push_back()` calls more easy to read. That said, start small: Remove a single element from the vector. If that causes problems, provide a [mcve] and a better description than "this is where I need help", because the latter basically reads like "please do my homework here". As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What do you mean "out of p"? Do you mean to ask how to select n elements p times?

Comment: Also do you want selection with or without replacement?

Comment: Aside from the actual question, you might want to put your code (and code in the future) on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are some things you do that are somewhat tedious, costing you time and making your program less readable. For example, you can easily initialize a vector like `vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};` instead of dozens of `push_back` calls, and your condition `if (i >= a.size())` is useless as it can't be true at that point. Again, aside from there being more direct solutions like in the answers below.

Comment: Question is unclear, since task which code should solve is unclear (not explained in text and code does't help to understand the issue too).

Comment: @Marek R Can you please tell why the question is unclear and why the task the code should solve is important so as I may clarify it. I think I explained what I needed to do but I don't think I need to give why I need to do it. Do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main () {

  // Better to initilize the vector like this instead of using multiple push_back
  std::vector<int> a;
  for (int i=10; i<36; ++i)
    a.push_back (i);

  // Here is another method to initilize your vector:
//   std::vector<int> a {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
//                       23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35};

  // Here you loop over all elements and only select the three first elements
  // of every six elements:
  for (int i=0; i<a.size(); ++i) 
    if (i%6 < 3)
      std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The % operator gives the remainder of a division of two int values.

Comment: If you would now also add an explanation, I'd give you an upvote. Please understand that a beginner will not necessarily understand what the modulo operator does and why it works here.   And you might want to consider to replace the `push_back` calls with list initialization to make the code as clean as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your code friend. If i'm not mistaken, the code tries to display an inextisting value from the array a[36]. Anyway, thanks for the proposition, it is much shorter than my example.

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA, The for loop in the code that I posted above, iterates from the first element which is a[0] to the last element which is a[25]. If you try to access the a[36] which does not exist you will receive a Segmentation Fault error.

Comment: my bad, I didn't verify well. Thanks, your code was ok

Answer (score 1):

Reorganize your vector so that each element is 3 `int`s

```
vector< std::tuple<int, int, int> > a = {10,11,12,13, ... };
```

Then use every other element, eg.:

```
for (size_t i{}; i<a.size(); ++i) {
  if (i%2 != 0) {
   std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd assume that in general the code is to work for any vector with any `n` and `p` given, like `vector<int> extract_n_of_p(const vector<int>& vec, size_t n, size_t p)`.

Comment: Thanks darune for the proposition. It works for the example, however, my data structure is not always a cluster of 3 elements out of 6 but can be variable.